# reading from a file and getting all strings after a string

Tags: c++, stream, filestream, stringstream

I have something like this:

```
while (getline(names_f, line) && getout == true)
{
    istringstream linestream(line);
    linestream >> student_id >> student_name >> student_surname;
```

As long as I have a function to consider if there is a middle name in the name, I need to have the whole line after `student_id` (`student_name >> student_surname`)

Is it possible to parse this reading from end of `student_id`?

Comment: I guess `getout` is bool, it gets `true` or `false`. `getout == true` gets the same `true` or `false`. Using `getout == true` in a condition is nonsense.

Comment: `names_f` and `linestream` are input streams. You use `getline` with `names_f`. What does prevent you from using `getline` with `linestream` after `student_id`?

Comment: Yes, just use `getline` (I think I understood you right).

Comment: *"I have something like this:"* -- using code to describe your situation is a bad idea. It's an even worse idea when the code does not function as desired. Please add more text to describe your scenario, what you want to accomplish, and why your current attempt is inadequate. I promise that there is no extra charge for using more words.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions let you do that and, besides, check if every line is correct from a syntax point of view (e.g. if they start with a number, if they have `n` fields, and so on).

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/nfbEhbK4e)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <string>  // getline

int main() {
    std::stringstream iss{
        "1 John Smith\n"
        "2 Sarah Connor\n"
        "3 Peter Gabriel\n"
        "4 Donal Duck\n"
        "5 Wesley Snipes\n"
    };

    for (std::string line{}; std::getline(iss, line); ) {
        std::regex pattern{R"(\d+\s+(\S+\s+\S+\s*))"};
        std::smatch matches{};
        if (std::regex_match(line, matches, pattern)) {
            std::string rest_of_line{ matches[1] };
            fmt::print("'{}'\n", rest_of_line);
        }
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   'John Smith'
//   'Sarah Connor'
//   'Peter Gabriel'
//   'Donal Duck'
//   'Wesley Snipes'
```